# getURLParameter For landing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the url parameters displayed on my landing page but its not working.

```html
<script>
  function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURI(
      (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search) || [, null])[1] || ''
    );
  }
</script>
<br>
<h1><b>Your <script>document.write(getURLParameter("devicebrand") + (" ") + getURLParameter("devicemodel"))</script>might be infected with <span id="blink"> (6)</span>Viruses!</b></h1>
```

All I get on the Landing Page is:

Your might be Infected with Viruses

When i force the value in url with:

This is the url

```
 www.domain.com/page.html?devicebrand=Apple&devicemodel=Iphone
```

Nothing happens

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Works for me if I make sure I pass something and run when the page is loaded. Don't use document.write

Also do not scare people.

```js
function getURLParameter(name, srch) {
  srch = srch || location.search;
  return decodeURI(
    (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(srch) || [, null])[1] || ''
  );
}

window.onload = function() {
  var loc = "#devicebrand=iPhone&devicemodel=6S";
  document.getElementById("devicebrand").innerHTML = getURLParameter("devicebrand", loc)
  document.getElementById("devicemodel").innerHTML = getURLParameter("devicemodel", loc)

}
```

```html
<br>
<h1><b>Your <span id="devicebrand"></span> <span id="devicemodel"></span> might be infected with <span id="blink"> (6)</span>Viruses!</b></h1>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer mplungjan, I am absolute novice where do i put my text "Your might be Infected with Viruses"?

Comment: The text can now be anywhere. My code lives in script tags normally in head

Comment: Ok I understand! thanks

Ive tested the new link on my android now it still says iphone though

var loc = "#devicebrand=iPhone&devicemodel=6S"  Is this what i use, or an example?